# No mapping exists from object type when attempting to insert unhandled exceptions to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am writing a code snippet that will catch all unhandled exceptions and store them in a database.

The code breaks at

```
int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
```

and the error is

> No mapping exists from object type System.RuntimeType to a known managed provider native type.

All of the solutions I have read thus far say to append .text to the variable being passed in as if it were a text box. Am I supposed to declare the data types in order to get them inserted into the database?

I have put the exceptions into variables and added the `DateTime.Now` to the query but still receive the same error about no mapping exists from object type. I step through the code before it gets to `int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` and all the values are showing up. For some reason when the program attempts to write to the database it needs some kind of mapping. I suspect it has something to do with the SQL command syntax or implicitly stating the data types for each column.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DownWithOOP
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            cLogger Logger = new cLogger();

            SqlConnection sqlConn1 = new SqlConnection("server=2.2.2.2;database=ExceptionLogging;uid=myusername;password=mypassword;");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.ExceptionLog (ExceptionType,ExceptionMessage,ExceptionSource,TargetSiteModule,TargetSiteName,StackTrace,HelpLink,ExceptionDate) VALUES (@ExceptionType, @ExceptionMessage, @ExceptionSource, @TargetSiteModule, @TargetSiteName, @StackTrace, @HelpLink, @ExceptionDate)", sqlConn1);

            //try
            //{
            //    throw new CustException();
            //}

            try
            {
                int value = 1 / int.Parse("0");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                sqlConn1.Open();

                Logger.Log("****************************************************************");
                Logger.Log("");

                var exType = ex.GetType();
                Console.WriteLine("Exception Type = {0}", exType);
                Logger.Log("Exception Type = " + exType);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExceptionType", exType);

                var exMessage = ex.Message;
                Console.WriteLine("Message = {0}", exMessage);
                Logger.Log("Message = " + exMessage);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExceptionMessage", exMessage);

                var exSource = ex.Source;
                Console.WriteLine("Source = {0}", exSource);
                Logger.Log("Source = " + exSource);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExceptionSource", exSource);

                var exTargetSiteName = ex.TargetSite.Module.Name;
                Console.WriteLine("TargetSiteModule = {0}", exTargetSiteName);
                Logger.Log("TargetSiteModule = {0}" + exTargetSiteName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TargetSiteModule", exTargetSiteName);

                var exTargetSite = ex.TargetSite;
                Console.WriteLine("TargetSite = {0}", exTargetSite);
                Logger.Log("TargetSite = " + exTargetSite);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TargetSiteName", exTargetSite);

                var exStackTrace = ex.StackTrace;
                Console.WriteLine("StackTrace = {0}", exStackTrace);
                Logger.Log("StackTrace = " + exStackTrace);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StackTrace", exStackTrace);

                var exHelpLink = ex.HelpLink;
                Console.WriteLine("HelpLink = {0}", exHelpLink);
                Logger.Log("HelpLink = " + exHelpLink);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HelpLink", exHelpLink);

                var dt = DateTime.Now;
                Console.WriteLine("ExceptionDate = {0},", dt);
                Logger.Log("ExceptionDate = " + dt);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExceptionDate", dt);

                Logger.Log("");
                Logger.Log("****************************************************************");

                int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }    

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First off, you should simplify your work and add `@using System.Data.SqlClient`.  Then use shorthand like `SqlCommand cmd = SqlCommand(" ");`.  Next you open your Sql connection, but do not close it.  Also, for simplicity, you should assign both your connection string and inserts to their own variables.

Comment: As for your question, yes.  Add something like `var error = ex.StackTrace;`  `cmd.Parameters.AddValues("@StackTrace", error);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :** You are not adding `ExceptionDate` parameter to your query.

**Solution :** You need to add `ExceptionDate` as below:

Try This:

```
DateTime dt=DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("ExceptionDate = {0},", dt.ToString());
Logger.Log("ExceptionDate = " + dt);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExceptionDate", dt.ToString());
```

Comment: I added your suggestion, however I still receive the same error.

Comment: use `exHelpLink.ToString()` and `exTargetSite.ToString()`